# Bootstrap ToolTip not showing on sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

The "Hover here" on the sidebar does not show the tooltip: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wpG3y6y5m)

It shows if the bootstrap css is excluded: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/KGVRmplG)

I tracked down the problem to this property:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

What's the right way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" class="sidebar-item-link" data-placement="bottom">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home glyph-sidebar"></span>
                <span class="sidebar-text">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Is there a non-JQuery solution?

Comment: Css hover wouldn't allow us to set the hover content programatically?